# Nodes in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I was assigned to make a grid of 4 roads in each direction and put "nodes" at the intersections as a destination or stopping point. My professor told me that he thinks that there is a way to do this by coordinates. I have looked for a node command but I haven't found one. Is there something similar to a node command?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're describing the following.

```
breed [nodes node]
to setup
  ca
  ask patches [sprout-nodes 1]
  ask turtles [create-links-with nodes-on neighbors4]
end
```

Comment: basically the same code is in Link Lattice Example, in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library

Comment: @SethTisue Ah, there it is.  I thought I recalled something, but I searched on "grid" instead of "lattice".